# Apparently there's an SQL Syntax error in this query when sent from PHP, but it runs fine on PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

It's all in the title really.

I've got this SQL query, ugly I know, but it should at least work... It works when I use it in PHPMyAdmin but when sent from PHP I get a syntax error from MySQL. :(

```
INSERT INTO `shortname_revisions` (old_shortname , new_shortname) VALUES ('$old', '$new');

UPDATE `soft_data` SET shortname = REPLACE(shortname ,'$old', '$new');
UPDATE `shot_data` SET shortname = REPLACE(shortname ,'$old', '$new');
UPDATE `virus_scanning` SET shortname = REPLACE(shortname ,'$old', '$new');
UPDATE `lang_translations` SET shortname = REPLACE(shortname ,'$old', '$new');
UPDATE `ratings` SET shortname = REPLACE(shortname ,'$old', '$new');
UPDATE `file_data` SET shortname = REPLACE(shortname ,'$old', '$new');
```

The `$new` and `$old` variables when pasted into PHPMyAdmin to test, would contain any string. Use `$old = "media-player"; $new = "video-player";` as examples.

Also, I'm not sure of the correct use of the back ticks and where they should be and when, maybe that's part the problem.

For everyone asking about the error, sorry, I didn't post it. And I sure ain't about to go and recreate the error to paste it here. It was a pretty generic "You have a syntax error in roughly this square quarter mile of code somewhere" error.

Comment: Are you using `mysqli::multi_query`?

Comment: Are `$old` and `$new` escaped? E. g. with [mysql_real_escape()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Can we see the actual PHP code?

Comment: +1 to @Maerlyn's suggestion. By default, PHP's MySQL functions will only run the first query when multiple statements are passed in. Either break it up into 7 separate statements if you are on PHP < 5, or use multi_query.

Comment: it would be interesting to see the PHP code where you embed these queries. Currently, they are just a set of SQL statements. The syntax error in the query may well be caused by incorrectly encapsulating the SQL query in PHP variables.

Comment: In addition to what everyone else has suggested, i.e. either use mysqli::multi_query() or invoke mysql_query() per query, you may run all your UPDATE statements in a single query because they have no specific WHERE condition

Comment: The fun part is that without the OP mentioning the error, he/she already has a solution :-)

Comment: Hi, everyone. The php code was literally just a that, in a variable, then that variable used inside mysql_query(); I got excited about mysqli::multi_query, or mysqli_multi_query() but I'm not using MySQLi, I don't think. In any case, it didn't work when I tried. I've put the queries an array and I now loop through them, which works great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Each statement needs to be sent in a separate mysql_query() call.

2) The backticks are fine but unecessary as there are no embedded blanks in any of those table names

3) I don't know your data structure but UPDATE without a "where" clause could be considered to be slightly unusual (unless these are intentionally single-row tables)

Answer (score 2):

I tend to always removed back ticks just to keep my code consistent, but this won't make a difference and will not be causing the error.

If the code is working in PHPmyadmin then it could to be a problem with `$new` and `$old`, try testing it change `$new` and `$old` to be set values, e.g. `$new="newtest"` and `$old="oldtest"`, see if that works, if it does you know the error with your variables, post them if that is the case.

Also, you may want to just try one update, it may be that because you are trying to update all together in one query you are getting an error.